# Setting angularjs data inside ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying set a variable's value inside  ng click which is not working.

```
<a href="#newpage" ng-click="service.name='{{sub.cid}}'"> view</a>
```

But when i use plain text instead of angular data value it works fine.

```
<a href="#newpage" ng-click="service.name='abc'">
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: in link probably use stop.propagation();

Comment: what the benefit of using thsi ?

Comment: event.stopPropagation():Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove string interpolation and directly use `sub.cid`

```
<a href="#newpage" ng-click="service.name=sub.cid"> view</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and set values there. Remove logic from template

```
<a href="#newpage" ng-click="changeValue(sub.cid)"> view</a>
<a href="#newpage" ng-click="changeValue('abc')"> view</a>


function changeValue(val) {
  ctrl.service.name = val;
}
```